# How to detect when flutter app comes back from background?

Tags: flutter

I would like to detect when flutter app comes back from background.

In other SDKs for crossApp development, there is usually a listener when app changes this state.
Is there anything similar in flutter?

Answer (score 9):

```
class _AppState extends State<App> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
      
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //add an observer to monitor the widget lyfecycle changes
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    //don't forget to dispose of it when not needed anymore
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  late AppLifecycleState _lastState;    
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);

    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed && _lastState == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
      //now you know that your app went to the background and is back to the foreground
    }
    _lastState = state; //register the last state. When you get "paused" it means the app went to the background.
  }
}
```