# Flutter application restart instead of resuming after some time when switch to other applications

Tags: flutter

Hi i am developing a flutter application and i am using **getx statemanagment**. The problem is when i put application in background and use some other applications like whatsapp,youtube,play a game or listen music, after some time when i resume my application from recents it restarts and all progress is lost.
I have already tried different solutions like moveTaskToback(true) with native android function call

**Please help**, I have almost finished my important application.

Comment: What kind of test device are you using?
Have you tried it on other devices as well(like AVD)? Does the app behave the same?

Comment: @Csisanyi Not on every mobile . I used Nokia and Samsung phones on these two it not happened but Xiaomi and oppo it happens. Actually my application is taking heart rate data from polar fitness strap so the page displaying real time graphs and animation which are pretty well coded and optimized . any how Why on some phones this problem happens ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure on why this happens, but some manufacturers have their own restrictions on apps running in the background. Nothing you can really do from a flutter perspective, the app lifecycle is the same on all devices.

Here is a link where they share some tips how to deal with this on Xiaomi from the users perspective.

https://dontkillmyapp.com/xiaomi

From the developers perspective, as you can read on the bottom of the article, the are no common workarounds known yet.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Csisanyi. I will look further into it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59056665/how-to-detect-when-flutter-app-comes-back-from-background?rq=3